# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException; data parcel size N bytes after scroll between tabs and open new activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have view pager with 15 tabs each tab has list of cards and pagination,
after so many scroll between tabs and then select one card from list, I open new activity and send selected object as Parcelable.
Then app crash and i got

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 534140 bytes
```

Even though i don't send any bitmap or huge arrays of strings, it is just the response object from server as below:

```
open class Content() : Listable, Parcelable, RealmObject() {
    var key: String = ""
    var screenName: String = ""
    var id: String? = null
    var title: String? = null
    var body: String? = null
    var type: String? = null
    var featuredImage: FeaturedImage? = null
    var sourceUrl: String? = null
    var isBreaking: Boolean? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
    var source: ContentSource? = null
    var video: ContentVideo? = null
    var isGallery: Boolean = false
    var gallery: RealmList<String>? = null
    var isSelected: Boolean = false
}
```

also I'm clearing bundle data on create view in each fragment:
`savedInstanceState?.clear()`

is that possible to exceed 1MB size and how to avoid this exception ?

Comment: I assume that you are sending this `Content` object via an `Intent` extra. Temporarily remove that extra from the `Intent`. If that allows you to start the other activity reliably, then `Content` is the source of your difficulty. IMHO, passing a `RealmObject` between activities is scary.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what do you suggest to pass realm object between activities ?

Comment: Pass an identifier between activities, then get the object from Realm as needed.